# asp.net mvc routing and the mysterious 404

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I am new to .net mvc.
In a nutshell, I want to see my website so people can type:
mywebsite/John@Eric 
and get processed by the correct controller.

On the other hand, I'd like to be able to also specify direct actions such as:
mywebsite/GetPeople

and get proccessed by GetPeople action.

I have set up two routing rules in my application:

**First Route**

```
    routes.MapRoute("Default",
                    "{id}",
            new { controller = "Friends", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { controller = @"[^\.]*", id = @"(?i)[a-z]*@[a-z]*" }
        );
```

**Second Route**

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Friends",
        "{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Friends" }
        );
```

The first and default route works great, but then when I send a request like this: mywebsite/GetPeople
the cheacky index action takes over and reads GetPeople as if it were a parameter. Even though I added my real awesome regax, this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how your routes might look:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Friends",
        "{id}",
        new { controller = "Friends", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { id = @"(?i)[a-z]*@[a-z]*" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Friends", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Now `mywebsite/John@Eric` will be handled by the `Index` action of the `Friends` controller and `mywebsite/GetPeople` will be handled by the `GetFriends` action of the `Friends` controller.

Comment: @Darin, that's great. But what if both routes are handeled by the same controller - in this case "Friends". this is my case, and there seems to be a fixup.

Comment: @vondip, then try specifying `controller = "Friends"` in the `Default` route. I was confused by your question where you talked about `GetPeople` controller while in fact you want the `GetPeople` action on the `Friends` controller.

Comment: @Darin, fixed my mixup there with naming the action as a controller. Ok I tried it, but for my dismay it doesn't seem to work. Just as a quick reminder I have both routes mapped to the same controller. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: @vondip, I've updated my answer. Please see if the new routing configuration works for you.

Comment: @Darin, I seem to receive another error, originated from an earlier stage, back when I changed my project's name. In the error i am asked to specify the namespace of the controller, when I do it I receive the oringal error. Here's the current error:               The request for 'Friends' has found the following matching controllers:
CoolFriends.Web.Controllers.FriendsController
MyFbFriends.Web.Controllers.FriendsController

Comment: @vondip, it looks like you have two `FriendsController` defined in your application. You need to remove the old one or test it in a new application created from scratch (that's what I did and the routes worked fine).

Comment: I did it ages ago, why won't it work when specifying a namespace. Where could the application possibly store \ cache this?

Comment: If you renamed the project the old assembly might still exist in the `bin` folder and it still loaded.

Comment: @Darin, I want to thank you. Your followups are really very apperciated, good  luck sir.

Comment: @vondip, you are welcome. Good luck to you with your project.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the way routing works in MVC. It just matches incoming URLs with routes in the order the routes are declared in RegisterRoutes. In this case the GetPeople in the URL would match with the Id parameter as everything is optional. To fix this, I would add a default as the last route. It could be done as so

```
routes.MapRoute("", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Friends",action="Index" });
```

This would handle the GetMyPeople URL. You would need to have an Index action on it though. The MvcContrib has an excellent Test helper for testing out MVC routes before actually running it from the app. You can get the bits [here](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/)

Comment: this seems to still send the request to the same default handler with the the action as a parameter.

Comment: aah! I thought you had a controller named GetPeople based on your original question but it seems you had an action named GetPeople

Comment: If that had been the case, the fix I suggested should have worked.